# I have the code, memory and watch opened. How do i make sense of these hex values?

Tags: c++, c++14

I've been trying debugging in code::blocks. I'm a student.
I understand value written on left is the address of the variable x in memory written in hex. What about these weird numbers on its right?

Also, what is the 'bytes' menu? If I select 16 bytes (from drop down arrow menu) I get one row only (in the image there are 8, as 16*8=256) . Does this mean this variable x is using 16 bytes in memory (but if I issue a sizeof(x) command, it gives me 4). So what's happening here?

Thanks.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbDC0.png)

code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x=10;
    x=6;
    x=13;
    int y=12;
    cout<<&y<<endl<<sizeof(x);
    int z=19;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post your code as text not as an image.

Comment: The left most column in the hex editor is the address, middle is the byte values in the memory, and the right most column is the ASCII representation of the bytes stored in the row.

Comment: Sidenote: I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler optimized the whole function to `int main() { int y; cout << &y << endl << sizeof(int); return 0; }` since none of the values are used.

Comment: @DhirajWishal would you please elaborate on 'byte values' and how I can make sense of them in the case of above example?

Comment: @TedLyngmo you're right. it works either way though i guess.

Comment: Yes, `x` is pointless and assigning values to it (that you don't use)  is pointless. Initializing `y` with 12 is pointless and `z` is pointless.

Comment: @TedLyngmo you're really smart. The whole point of this post (and the code) is to understand debugging, not make an actual production value program.

Comment: Ok, just be sure you turn off optimizations when compiling or `x` and `z` may not be visible in the final program since they can be optimized away.

Answer (score 2):

**Basics** 
The smallest memory size that we can work with is 1 byte. To represent a byte in hex, you need two hex values (ie: `A0`). This is the basics in the hex editor/ viewer.

What you have when you debug memory is the memory portion which the application uses in the RAM. A typical hex editor/ viewer will look something like this,

```
 The address (A) | The values (in hex) (B)      |  ASCII representation (C)
    |            |             |                |          |
    V            |             V                |          V
0x000000         |  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |  . . . . . . . . . .
```

- The `A` column represents the base (beginning) address of the row.
- The `B` column shows the actual values stored at a given address. The first hex value (ie: `00` in this depiction) has the address of `0x000000`. The second one has the address of `0x000001` and so on.
- The `C` column contains the ASCII representation of the values shown in one column. Meaning that it shows what the values in the row looks like in ASCII.

`int` in C++ is 4 bytes in size (32 bits). In your example, the address of `x` is `0x61ff1c`. Right next to it, in the `B` column you get the value stored in little endian (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

The address of `y` is `0x61ff14` in the memory. Your image does not show it as the variable is stored at a memory location before the address of `x`.

The `Bytes` in the menus just lets you to decide how many bytes it should display starting from the address that you specified (in your case its the address of `x`).

Comment: An `int` isn't necessarily 32 bits. It's at least 16 bits, so 16, 32, 64 ... are all valid sizes for an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

> What about these weird numbers on its right?

The number on the extreme left is the memory address of the first byte (8 bits). In your image `0x61ff1c` is not the address of the entire row, just the first byte (`0d`). The address of the second byte is `0x61ff1d` and so on. If you check, the address to the left of the second row reads `0x61ff2c`, exactly a difference of 16 bytes.

Now, about the contents. Let's look at `0x61ff1c`, it contains `0x0d`. If you are using a CPU with the `x86` architecture, it is the opcode of an instruction that tells the CPU to perform a logical OR operation between the numbers in the next locations. The CPU does not understand C, it only understands binary. When you compile a C program, it gets converted from a `.c` file to an executable. The executable file can be directly executed by the CPU because all it contains is opcodes for instructions and data. The instruction set can be completely different for a CPU with another architecture; there `0xd` can mean something else. Your compiler takes care of generating the right instructions for your CPU.
What you are seeing is directly the binary contents of memory(in hex to make it simpler), which will be read by the CPU.

#### ASCII

To the extreme right is the textual representation of the instructions.
Ever tried opening an executable file in Notepad or another text editor? Basically, all computer files contain data in the form of 0s and 1s. It is the file type that tells the computer how to interpret it. When you create a text file in Notepad, it is interpreted as text/ASCII. For instance, the ASCII value of `A` is 65 or `0x41`. When the computer sees, `0x41`, it knows it is an `A`. But if your file type is not text but rather an executable, that same `0x41` could be an opcode for an instruction. When you open an executable with Notepad, you are interpreting CPU instructions as text. In your case `0xd` means OR for an executable, but you are trying to interpret as text. The character with the ASCII value `0x40`  is @, that's why you get an @ for the 7th column in the extreme right.